# Border css на половину круга

Tags: html, css

Ребят,как сделать чтобы было из этого:[image: Эллипс]

Получить при наведении это:[image: Эллипс:hover]

Не переворачивая объект типа:`transform: rotate(45deg);`

Comment: Посмотрите здесь  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-top-left-radius

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background: #333;
}
.circle-out {
  width: 98px;
  height: 98px;
  left: 1px;
  top: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
}
.circle:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #333 0%, #333 49%, #f33 50%, #f33 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="circle-out"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Хороший ответ (+) Просто и надёжно